# Fixtures are not adding to text file

Tags: c#, algorithm, scheduler, fixtures

I am currently working on a project which is a basketball simulation game and I am coming across a problem when generating the fixtures for games which are going to be played and I'm completely oblivious to what is causing the problem.

There are no errors that appear in the Error List but for some reason when the fixtures are supposed to be generated, I think there is an infinite loop happening but I'm not sure what is causing the problem.

I have separated the arrays which are used in the algorithm and the initial adding to text file from the algorithm below which is pasted in : http://pastebin.com/cLXi0Hm3 as i felt it would take up too much room.

Here is the algorithm which is to create these fixtures:

```
public static void Fixtures()
{
    List<string> SouthwestFixtures = new List<string>(); // Create a new list to store the games
    while (SouthwestFixtures.Count < 410) // Whilst length of fixtures is less than 410
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Southwest Division Fixtures
        /// </summmary>

        Random rnd = new Random(); // Generate a new random
        string SWTeam1 = Arrays.WCSouthwest[rnd.Next(Arrays.WCSouthwest.Length)]; // Select random home team
        string SWTeam2 = Arrays.WCSouthwest[rnd.Next(Arrays.WCSouthwest.Length)]; // Select random away team
        if (SWTeam1 == SWTeam2) // If they are the same teams
        {
            while (SWTeam1 == SWTeam2) // whilst they are equal to eachother
            {
                string newteam = Arrays.WCSouthwest[rnd.Next(Arrays.WCSouthwest.Length)];
                SWTeam2 = newteam; // generate new away team
            }
        }

        string fixture = string.Format("{0} v {1}", SWTeam1, SWTeam2); // convert it to a string               


        for (int i = 0; i <= 40; i++) // whilst i is 0
        {
            if (SouthwestFixtures.Contains(fixture)) // if fixture is already in fixtures stop
            { break; }
            else
            {
                SouthwestFixtures.Add(fixture);
                SouthwestFixtures.Add(fixture);
            } // add it
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// 4 Games Against 6 Out of Division Teams In Same Conference
        /// </summary>

        var WCNWList = Arrays.WCNorthwest.ToList();
        var WCPList = Arrays.WCPacific.ToList();
        var WCCombined = WCNWList.Concat(WCPList);
        var WCCombined1 = WCCombined.ToList();
        List<string> WCCombined2 = new List<string>(4);

        for (int i = WCCombined1.Count(); i > 6; i--)
        {
            int WCRemoveTeam = rnd.Next(WCCombined1.Count());
            WCCombined2.Add(WCCombined1[WCRemoveTeam]);
            WCCombined1.RemoveAt(WCRemoveTeam);
        }

        var WCCombined1Array = WCCombined1.ToArray();
        var WCCombined2Array = WCCombined2.ToArray();

        string SWTeam = Arrays.WCSouthwest[rnd.Next(Arrays.WCSouthwest.Length)]; // Select random home team
        string WCTeam = WCCombined1Array[rnd.Next(WCCombined1Array.Length)]; // Select random away team


        string fixturehome = string.Format("{0} v {1}", SWTeam, WCTeam); // convert it to a string
        string fixtureaway = string.Format("{0} v {1}", WCTeam, SWTeam);

        for (int i = 0; i <= 30; i++) // whilst i is 0
        {
            if (SouthwestFixtures.Contains(fixturehome) || SouthwestFixtures.Contains(fixtureaway)) // if fixture is already in fixtures break
            { break; }
            else
            {
                SouthwestFixtures.Add(fixturehome);
                SouthwestFixtures.Add(fixturehome);
                SouthwestFixtures.Add(fixtureaway);
                SouthwestFixtures.Add(fixtureaway);
            } // add it
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// 3 Games vs Remaining Out of Divison Teams In Same Conference
        /// </summary>
        string WCTeam2 = WCCombined2Array[rnd.Next(WCCombined2Array.Length)]; //Grab team from list of teams to play 3 games against

        string fixturehome2 = string.Format("{0} v {1}", SWTeam, WCTeam2); // convert it to a string
        string fixtureaway2 = string.Format("{0} v {1}", WCTeam2, SWTeam);

        for (int i = 0; i <= 20; i++)
        {
            if (SouthwestFixtures.Contains(fixturehome2) || SouthwestFixtures.Contains(fixtureaway2)) // if fixture is already in fixtures break
            { break; }
            else
            {
                SouthwestFixtures.Add(fixturehome2);
                SouthwestFixtures.Add(fixtureaway2);
            }
            int homeoraway = rnd.Next(1, 2);
            if (homeoraway == 1)
            {
                SouthwestFixtures.Add(fixturehome2);
            }
            else
            {
                SouthwestFixtures.Add(fixtureaway2);
            }
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Eastern Conference Fixtures
        /// </summary>

        string ECTeam = Arrays.ECTeams[rnd.Next(Arrays.ECTeams.Length)]; // Select random away team

        string fixtureh = string.Format("{0} v {1}", SWTeam, ECTeam); // convert it to a string
        string fixturea = string.Format("{0} v {1}", ECTeam, SWTeam);


        for (int i = 0; i <= 75; i++) // whilst i is 0
        {
            if (SouthwestFixtures.Contains(fixtureh) || SouthwestFixtures.Contains(fixturea)) // if fixture is already in fixtures break
            { break; }
            else
            {
                SouthwestFixtures.Add(fixtureh);
                SouthwestFixtures.Add(fixturea);
            } // add it
        }


    } // loop through till it is done
}
```

I am pretty sure it goes wrong when it is generating both the last two fixture sections (the 3 games against 4 teams and the eastern conference games as everything prior to this works, but I still cannot figure out where it is going wrong)

I'd be grateful if anyone was to help point out where this is going wrong.

Comment: Tips: Programming is similar to asking good questions: Focus on the simplest thing. For programming, function decomposition is a process and decoupling is attribute of the output of that process. For example, sections with comments like "/// 3 Games vs Remaining Out of Divison Teams In Same Conference" beg to be separate functions (it might be hard to decouple such sections, though). An easy thing to decouple is the generation of two distinct integers in a range; definitely move that out to a separate function. You'll end up finding your problem or being able to ask a more focused question.

Comment: You while loop always test for same value and never exits.  Change while to for :             for (int count = 0; count < SouthwestFixtures.Count; count++) // Whilst length of fixtures is less than 410

Comment: @jdweng his fixtures count is 0 at the start of the loop and he adds as he goes along though

Comment: well the counting is not working.  Using a for loop guarantees you don't get stuck in an endless loop.

Comment: Please reduce your question to a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem. Be sure to explain precisely what that code does and how that's different from what you want. Please also note that "chatty" text in questions and answers, such as pre-emptive apologies, thanks, etc., is discouraged and unnecessary. See also [ask] for more information.

Comment: I will note that in every place in your method where you might add an element to the `SouthwestFixtures` list, there is a condition that allows that add to be skipped. Without a good code example, I can't say for sure what would happen, but it's theoretically possible for your code to get into a state where it can no longer find anything to add to the list, and so loops forever. You should spend some time learning how to use the debugger; you should be able to wait for the program to stop responding (i.e. infinite loop), then break in the debugger and step through the code to see what's wrong.